# window.open(url,"_blank") opens window but widens across the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, href, window.open

I am facing an issue where when I click on a link and opens in a new window. It opens with the correct size window but then the window widens across the screen. My Javascript function makes an Ajax call using jQuery.
Kindly help me out on how to avoid widening the window unless i maximize it.

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url : "xyx",
  data: xyz,
  success: function(portletURL){
    window.open(portletURL, "_blank", "directories=no,height=640,location=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=no,toolbar=no,width=830");
  } 
});
```

Comment: The new window opens with the given dimensions but widens when the whole page within that window is loaded

Comment: So your issue is not relevant to posted code. Some code inside popup make it resize i guess. Can you edit popup window code or not?

Comment: Well shouldn't it load within the given dimensions ?
window.open is the popup window code. I dint get your question. Can you please rephrase it?

Comment: What code contains the new opened window? I guess it contains some code which makes it resized. So can you edit content of new window or not?

Comment: Ok that piece of code is a URL mapping. so that comes from the server. no dimensions set for that.

Answer (score 0):

Is the width of the page you're loading within this window the same (or less) as the window width you specified? I suspect the reason for the window to widen across the screen like this is because of that. Try setting resizable to no

Comment: I tried setting resizable to no. But that din't work. The Page width seems to be more than the window width but I have set scrollbars to yes so that should have taken care of the dimensions. Why does it widen when the page gets loaded in the new window?

Comment: scrollbars is on so there shouldn't be a sizing issue then, try put the width next to height? Another thing you can do is set the outerWidth and outerHeight sizes and see if that helps (but first try height=640,width=830 and the rest of your settings

Comment: No that dint work. Although I just noticed that even when I have set the scrollbars to yes, they aren't enabled when the page width exceeds the window width, while opening. Any Idea?

Comment: try good old 1 and 0. That's what the documentation says. I think maybe it might be your browser not allowing you to set it as "yes" or "no"?

Comment: 1 = true / yes. 0 = false / no

Comment: I tried all of that. I played alot with the properties but wondering why arent the scrollbars displaying.

Comment: which browser are you using?

Comment: FireFox. I think they are getting overridden somewhere.